# How can I send multiple get requests to a URL in a C# console app?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to send multiple GetRequest to a URL at the same time, and have it loop automatically. Can anyone give me the C# console coding?

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace MakeAGETRequest_charp
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1.
/// </summary>
class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sURL;
        sURL = "EXAMPLE.COM";

        int things = 5;
        while (things > 0)
        {
            WebRequest wrGETURL;
            wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

            string sLine = "1";
            int i = 0;

                i++;
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (things > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, sLine);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can help you fix your code if you post what you've already coded so far. Otherwise I suggest you perform a quick google on how to do a GetRequest at all and then come back here if you can't modify the code to fit your requirements. Without some sample of what you've tried so far, you won't find too many people helping out...

Comment: This is what I have, but I'd like it to send multiple requests at the same time. The more I can get it to send, the better.
Edit:I'm new here and im having trouble pasting the code, it says its too big.

Answer (score 2):

JK presents a synchronous version.  The second URL won't be retrieved until a response is received from the first URL request.

Here's an asynchronous version:

```
List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>();
uris.Add(new Uri("http://example.com"));
uris.Add(new Uri("http://example2.com"));

foreach(Uri u in uris)
{
    var client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadDataCompleted += OnDownloadCompleted;
    client.DownloadDataAsync(u); // this makes a GET request
}

...

void OnDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff here.  check e for completion, exceptions, etc.
}
```

See [DownloadDataAsync documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync.aspx)

Comment: Do you need to create a WebClient for each request, or can you create it and set the callback handler outside the loop to re-use it?

Comment: I'd create one each request.  I'm not certain, but I think it might be intended that way.  For example, the WebClient's CancelAsync() method does not specify which pending operation (if multiple were allowed) to cancel.

Comment: You're right.  I have just had a play around with a WebClient and was given the following NotSupportedException when I tried to set off two concurrent downloads - "WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations".  You learn something new every day. :)

Comment: I ran into this yesterday when I wanted to cancel multiple requests :D

Comment: It's great when you can pass on freshly learned knowledge, isn't it? :)  All this time I have been using WebClients and never knew they didn't support concurrent downloads.  I know it would have bitten me first time I needed to do so.

Comment: Im very sorry, but I'm quiet new to this. I have coding to send a single get request and then it loops. How could I put that into what I have so far? Also how can I show someone coding that is too big to post in a comment?

Comment: Could you edit the original question to include the source code?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>();
uris.Add(new Uri("http://example.com"));
uris.Add(new Uri("http://example2.com"));

foreach(Uri u in uris)
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(u);
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Comment: this is not what the user wants he wants at same time not one by one using threads or taks or asynchorous will do the effect